# Enable/Disable SectionIndexer of ListView

Tags: android, listview, sections

Is there any way to disable/enable the sectioning programmatically ?

So I can choose between normal fastScroll and Indexes without making two adapters ?

Comment: you should post your problem with code and some details and also the same for the answer. Just not enough details to help the community in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it finaly on my own. You only have to make the Array with the Letters empty and voila you got a normal Fastscroll functionality.